# Attributes NSDictionary construction crash

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am getting the following error when the app calls the line:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
```

Why?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

Here is the original code, which dynamically determines the height of a cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row==0)  { //postcell
        return 500.0; //TODO add some autolayout stuff for this case...
    } else  { //comment cell
        CommentCell * commentCell=(CommentCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGSize labelHeight = [self heigtForCellwithString:commentCell.bodyLabel.text andLabelWidth:commentCell.bodyLabel.frame.size.width withFont:commentCell.bodyLabel.font];
        return labelHeight.height; // the return height + your other view height
    }
}

-(CGSize)heigtForCellwithString:(NSString *)stringValue andLabelWidth:(CGFloat)labelWidth withFont:(UIFont *)font{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(labelWidth,9999); // Replace 300 with your label width //TODO replace
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
    CGRect rect = [stringValue boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                            options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                         attributes:attributes
                                            context:nil];
    return rect.size;
}
```

Comment: `font` is `nil`. This means either `commentCell` is `nil` or `commentCell.bodyLabel` is `nil`. Use the debugger and see which one it is.

Comment: You are correct. Commentcell is nil. It seems you cannot reference a specific cell in the tableview in heightforrow method because the cells are not yet loaded?

Comment: If you want to put up an answer I'll mark it as right.

Answer (score 0):

If these are vanilla table view cells your can return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` from `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and not worry about implementing custom row sizing.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error log you are inserting nil to dictionary. As we can not insert null in dictionary in Objective c. May be font is nil. Put break point just before the line and move you mouse cursor above 
***font*** present on the line mentioned by you. If it is nil or not. If it is nil then it will crash.